# How to type function with variadic number of generic type variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, variadic-functions

Given

```
type Loadable<T> = () => T
type LoadableCombinerResult<T> = { result: T }
```

I would like define types for a function with input like this:

- variable number of `Loadable<ResponseDataType>` inputs with different `ResponseDataType` for each input,
- `combiner` taking data results of above loadables.

The function would take care of handling error states and loading progress of loadables, plus few other things. The function would call `combiner` only if all loadables are successfully loaded.

This is possible to implement in untyped JavaScript. However, I fail to properly type it in TypeScript.

Non-variadic typing would look like this:

```js
function useLoadableCombiner2<TResult, T1, T2>(
  combiner: (data1: T1, data2: T2) => TResult,
  loadable1: Loadable<T1>,
  loadable2: Loadable<T2>
): LoadableCombinerResult<TResult> { ... }

function useLoadableCombiner3<TResult, T1, T2, T3>(
  combiner: (data1: T1, data2: T2, data3: T3) => TResult,
  loadable1: Loadable<T1>,
  loadable2: Loadable<T2>,
  loadable3: Loadable<T3>
): LoadableCombinerResult<TResult> { ... }

function useLoadableCombiner4<TResult, T1, T2, T3, T4>(
  combiner: (data1: T1, data2: T2, data3: T3, data4: T4) => TResult,
  loadable1: Loadable<T1>,
  loadable2: Loadable<T2>,
  loadable3: Loadable<T3>,
  loadable4: Loadable<T4>
): LoadableCombinerResult<TResult> { ... }

function useLoadableCombinerN<...>(...): LoadableCombinerResult<TResult> { ... }
```

Is it possible to type this in TypeScript as one function in one declaration?

It could be an array/typed-tuple instead of variable number of arguments.

The goal is to put in variable number of loadables in, and then being able to call typed `combiner` with all the data, after a successful load of everything.

Comment: _"It could be an array/typed-tuple instead of variable number of arguments"_ - do that then, like [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2c7162143bbbf567ccecc64105010699fa7a2128/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts#L201-L207).

Comment: [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvzErW) shows a possible approach using mapped tuple types (with toy definitions of `Loadable` and `LoadableCombinerResult`). Does it work for you? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz in the mean time, a colleague of mine produced [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYIEYBsIB4AqA+KAXigAoBKIgnAWAChRJZEUMIBhOAW1QEsA7CACcAShADOAV3TBcBYgG8og8VOAAuKDigBfOnQBmEvgGNgPOHygSxEeMjSYO3fkIAsuUZOkAaTTB5iwFAQAB7AEHxIYlZ8ANZ8cADufADaALp4JHRQUMZcvAKCGiQAdGXoAep+lRSEVJ6q3tlQZSXozA7iGoopAJJQ-FCxECBw+tWBaRp2LJi4-oF9GTp0ZNMdrE4FQg3SHirSBPLNOcAAFoJJUACigpeCJABECUE8nGCYnBHhSI8UdLpaHQ8nxAlAAG5EKw2GadLYuQTuQKCfgAc18KT4Em4Ql8yLRvix6HQGSytByOVK5RqlCgFUCJQAVnB+OQmuSKeRaQBmdkU0i1AiPR58zmCqBE9CrErKLzANpwYwIRxcMAIZR0IA)

Comment: @jcalz almost the same, just using `unknown` instead of `any`, which is probably more technically correct. It means, that type is `unknown` to the function, and therefore it can't store `any` element in the array.

Comment: @jcalz I'll accept the answer, as it works for me - I've already finished the function implementation - and, I would like it to be available for other people, as this topic is quite hard to google out. Though, wondering why there is already a `Close (1)` vote on this question. Is StackOverflow becoming toxic, that almost every hard question about any technology gets vote-closed or down-voted?

Comment: ① There isn't an appreciable difference between `T extends any[]` and `T extends unknown[]` and you can always store an `any` type somewhere that expects `unknown`.  Use whichever you prefer. ② I'll write up an answer when I get a chance ③ I didn't vote to close so I don't know why except that I can see that it's marked as "lacks debugging details", possibly because you didn't supply definitions for `Loadable` etc?  But that's pure speculation on my part, and I'm not prepared to digress further by discussing voting and toxicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` to represent [the rest parameter list](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to `combiner`, and then [map over that tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to get the type of the `loadable` rest parameter:

```
declare function useLoadableCombiner<R, T extends any[]>(
  combiner: (...data: T) => R,
  ...loadable: { [I in keyof T]: Loadable<T[I]> }
): LoadableCombinerResult<R>;
```

Now when you call `useLoadableCombiner`, the type checker can infer `T` either from the parameter types of `combiner` or, if you don't annotate those, from the return types of each element of `loadable`:

```
const x = useLoadableCombiner(
  //  ^? const x: LoadableCombinerResult<boolean>
  (str, num, dat) => str.length + num > dat.getTime(),
  () => "a", () => 1, () => new Date()
)
```

Here `T` is inferred from `loadable` is of type `[Loadable<string>, Loadable<number>, Loadable<Date>]`, and then `combiner` is checked (you can see how even though we don't annotate `str`, `num`, and `dat`, the type checker knows their types from `loadable`) and returns a `boolean`, and thus `x` is of type `LoadableCombinerResult<boolean>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYIEYBsIB4AqA+KAXigAoBKIgnAKFElkRQwgGE4BbVASwDsIAnAEoQAzgFd0wXAWIBvKP1ETgALig4oAX2rUkEAMboEiqADMxPfcC5weUMSIjxkaTG068BWQQBp1UCAAPYAgeJBEoBB4QAG0AXTwSaigofQ5uPn41EgA6PJRgBDUcCkICX2SoPJz0RlcINXkYgEkoXigAawgQOFN1OLVnJkxcFoStajJBuuZ3DIFhcUlvPABuHTSeEWAoQKJ7RyH6uc9+JJSAeguUgD0AflTbbd3pl1n008XlLFQ4OEwonhKiRtvw-DwxOw-AVSgRQTVQgBzYAACygAGooBD2FACAUcoiIMAcFx2BByD5gbCoAAiBA0vzkShQACMjOpfAA7lAACIIELkSbUIA)

Comment: Thank you for writing up the answer with details and explanation.

Comment: For me, the unknown part - trick here - the solution to the core of the problem - is `{ [I in keyof T]: Loadable<T[I]> }`. This syntax allows to map a tuple of elements of different types to a tuple of wrappers, where wrapper is generic, and each wrapper of element uses matching element type from original tuple.